# Alarm not working in Game Maker

Tags: game-maker

In Game maker... after the instance is destroyed I want there to be few seconds delay before the game moves to main menu room. I have added alarm 0 after the instance destroy and in alarm 0 i have added message box saying game over and also move to room - main menu. But that alarm is not triggering. No action is taking place after the instance is destroyed. If I don't use alarm the message box pops up before the instance is destroyed completely. What can be done about it? I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 5):

Alarm of course does not work, because you destroy the object in which is the alarm.
The easiest way - to create a new object (as an example, with the name `obj_wait`), in create event write:

```
alarm [0] = room_speed * 3;
```

and inside the `alarm0`:

```
room_goto (r_main_menu); // your menu room
```

When destroying of your object, create an instance:

```
instance_create (0, 0, obj_wait);
```

Comment: @Dmi7ry....Thank you so much for your help! It works like a charm... I got the mistake I was doing....Thank you so much..